# PHP - Need to fill array from text

Tags: php, arrays, string, search

I need to fill an array from all text, within a string that begins with `[` and ends with `]`.

For Example:

> here is some text [to do] and something else [/find] for the way this
>   works is [object] and [tada]

This should return an array like so:

```
array('[to do]', '[/find]', '[object]', '[tada]');
```

How can I do this quickly? And in the same order that's in within the text?

There can be any characters at all within the square brackets. I just need to grab them all, plus both brackets.

Comment: In the PHP Language.  Sorry bout that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$subject = "here is some text [to do] and something else [/find] for the way this works is [object] and [tada]";
preg_match_all("/\[[^\[\]]+\]/", $subject, $out);
var_dump($out[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `preg_match_all`.

`preg_match_all('/\[(.*?)\]/', $text_to_filter, $array);`

`$array` will contain your matches.

It won't work with nested square brackets, though.